# groupby and sum by specify row type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a groupby and sum by specific row type, for example 3 company sell shoe, coat and slipper, I want to groupby company and add them by specific sell type shoe + coat.

[image]

Text input -

```
  company  selltype  price
0       a      shoe     34
1       a      coat     23
2       a  slippers     12
3       b      shoe     55
4       b      coat     34
5       b  slippers     23
6       c      shoe     65
7       c      coat     34
8       c  slippers     12
```

Comment: So, what is your code for that up till now? You should post it and explain why it isn't working as intended, so people can help fixing the bugs

Comment: Sorry flen and thanks coldspeed for your help, I realize there’s another simple approach to this that is replace coat with shoe and do a groupby on shoe, which do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
treatsame={'shoe':'coat'}
df.groupby([df.company,df.selltype.replace(treatsame)]).\
    agg(lambda x :x.sum() if x.dtype=='int64' else '+'.join(x)).\
        reset_index('selltype',drop=True)
Out[40]: 
          selltype  price
company                  
a        shoe+coat     57
a         slippers     12
b        shoe+coat     89
b         slippers     23
c        shoe+coat     99
c         slippers     12
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` + `agg` -

```
i = df.selltype.isin(['shoe', 'coat'])
j = i.ne(i.shift()).cumsum()

f = {'selltype' : '+'.join, 'price' : 'sum'}
df.groupby(['company', j], as_index=False).agg(f)

  company   selltype  price
0       a  shoe+coat     57
1       a   slippers     12
2       b  shoe+coat     89
3       b   slippers     23
4       c  shoe+coat     99
5       c   slippers     12
```

---

**Details**

We need to group on two predicates -

1. the `company` column, and
2. the merchandise being sold

Since we consider shoes and coats together, we'll need to create a custom series that reflects this, which is computed using `i` and `j` -

```
i = df.selltype.isin(['shoe', 'coat'])
i

0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
8    False
Name: selltype, dtype: bool
```

```
j = i.ne(i.shift()).cumsum()
j

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    4
6    5
7    5
8    6
Name: selltype, dtype: int64
```

Now, all that's left is the grouping operation -

```
df = df.groupby(['company', j], as_index=False).agg(f)
```

To get your exact output, you can do a little more here, use `pd.Series.where` -

```
df.company = df.company.where(df.company.ne(df.company.shift()), '')
df

  company   selltype  price
0       a  shoe+coat     57
1           slippers     12
2       b  shoe+coat     89
3           slippers     23
4       c  shoe+coat     99
5           slippers     12
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few more steps and not as concise as the other answers, but breaks down the process step by step

```
# read the data in from clipboard copied off stackoverflow
df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
# sum the coats with shoes
dfnoslip = df2[df2.selltype != 'slippers']
dfnoslipnext = dfnoslip.groupby('company', as_index=False).sum()
dfnoslipnext.insert(1, 'selltype', 'shoe+coat')
# get just slippers
dfnocoatshoe = df2.query('selltype != "coat" & selltype != "shoe"')
# combine and sort
dfnewcombine = dfnocoatshoe.append(dfnoslipnext)
dfnewcombine = dfnewcombine.sort_values('company')
dfnewcombine
```